# Is it wrong to use 'include' for redirecting user to another PHP file?

Tags: php, redirect, php-include

I have created a HTML login form which checks for email and password authentication and then redirects to the user account.

My PHP code is as below:

```
 <?php  

 require('connect.php');//for connection to the database.


$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE pemail='$email' and password='$password'";

$result1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$usercount = mysql_num_rows($result1);




if ($usercount == 1){
include 'myaccount.php';
}


else{

echo "Invalid Details.";
echo "<a href='login.php'>Back to Login</a>";
}
```

Here, I have tried `include` to redirect to the user account...and it works fine.

Though my instructor says me that it is wrong to use `include` and you should implement it in another ways.

Why it is wrong to use `include` to redirect to the user account? I searched for it but I didn't found the answer.

plz do not discourage...thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `header()` for redirect not `include()` ...

Comment: `include` is not used to redirect to other page. Its usage is to includes the contents of given file.

Comment: but why is the question...include works well in my project...Can you provide reason for using header() and not using include() in answer?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: AND you must never store unencrypted passwords ANYWHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your instructor is correct. [`include()`](http://php.net/include) is for including PHP code, not for redirecting. [`header()`](http://php.net/header) function does that, so use it. Using `include()` *works*, but that doesn't mean you should use it.

#### Why shouldn't you use `include`?

- `include()` is a function for "including" code from a different file. It loads and executes the code from the file and is not exclusively built for redirecting. On the other hand, the sole purpose of `header()` is to send raw HTTP headers, i.e. perform redirects and the like. Use that instead.
- If you have multiple lines of code in the file you're using for the redirect, `include()` will execute it completely, every time you perform a redirect. If your application uses redirects heavily, this would mean a performance loss and would result in a laggy application. Moreover, you'll be needlessly executing several lines of code if you're using `include()`. If you were to use `header()`, you could avoid this problem. (By calling `exit()` right after `header()`.)

#### More problems in your code:

- You're using `mysql_*` functions. The `ext/mysql` extension is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead.
- You're blindly injecting user input into your database query, thereby making it vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com). A user with malicious intent could technically cause troubles, or even delete your database entirely. Use PDO / MySQLi with [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to prevent this from happening. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114) for more details on how.

Comment: thank you very much...can you improve my code in answer?

Comment: I am a student and novice to PHP and don't know much more about it.

Comment: @krupal: Read [this article](http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/). That should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    if ($usercount == 1) {
        $redirect_url = "";//here goes your url where you want to redirect the user to
        header("Location: " . $redirect);
        exit();
    }
```

You should also look into `MySqli` or `PDO`

Comment: It also works...but as I asked I want to answer to the question 'Why it is wrong to use include instead of header()?'

Comment: This is just a simple explanation to give you an idea, suppose you have some formula in formula.php and you want to make use of this in another part of your program so you `include` formula.php, in this way you do not have to rewrite the same formula again, but if you want to redirect a user, you need to use a header. I hope this answers your question